# Block SSH to all but root user

Tags: ssh, permissions

How can I modify my `sshd_config` so that it blocks access to all users except the root user?

I've had a look and I tried

```
AllowUsers root
DenyUsers *
```

But that doesn't do anything

Comment: I'm curios why you want that, normally (and by default in many distributions) it is exactly the other way round for security reasons.

Comment: I use keyfile instead of passwords but the goal of this isn't to hide the root account its to reduce the complexity of monitoring

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried this myself, adding only the `AllowUsers root` line, which worked without a hitch. Probably an obvious question, but since you didn't mention it explicitly: did you restart the `sshd` service after making the modification?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Linux, you can use the pam_succeed_if.so PAM module (if your distro has it).  Other OSes may or may not have it so YMMV.

in /etc/pam.d/sshd:

```
account    sufficient   pam_succeed_if.so login = <username>
```

You can also allow specific groups, or numerical uids/gids, etc.

See http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_succeed_if for more information on this PAM Module.

Answer (score 0):

This method doesn't involve sshd_config, but the effect is the same.  I lockout all users except root when I need to do maintenance on my Linux hosts. Just remove the file when you're done.

```
echo "System maintenance in progress" > /run/nologin
```

Comment: Note that this only blocks users from accidentally logging in. If a user really want to login he can still do something like `ssh -t username@host /bin/bash`